# Mask only appears with double click

Tags: delphi

I need every value typed in my StringGrid to stay as a percentage.

**Example:**  If I type 60 I want it to appear as 60,0%.

I tried the following way but it does not work ... it only appears if I type, exit, and double click on the cell again .. (I also need it to only accept numbers)

```
procedure TfrmConfiguraClassificacao.listaFaixasGetEditMask(Sender: TObject;
  ACol, ARow: Integer; var Value: string);
begin
  if (ACol = 0) or (Acol = 1) then
  begin
    if listaFaixas.Cells[Acol, ARow] <> '' then
      Value := '99,9%';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That is because you only set the mask if the cell is not empty. You need to set it every time so that it is there before you start typing for the first time.

Comment: @Dsm 
Please, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not set your mask until you have typed something in the cell, which describes the symptoms you are seeing. Instead you should always set you mask based only on row/column, not on the contents:

```
procedure TfrmConfiguraClassificacao.listaFaixasGetEditMask(Sender: TObject;
  ACol, ARow: Integer; var Value: string);
begin
  if (ACol = 0) or (Acol = 1) then
  begin
    Value := '99,9%';
  end;
end;
```